# Spring Cloud Gateway Event Metrics

Tags: spring, prometheus, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there a way to track metrics like events created and consumed in spring cloud gateway? Like in Spring MVC, we can track tomcat threads status from grafana.

I have gone through a multiple documentations.

I have already monitored executor graphs, but no of active threads are always zero.